# Number of reactions per metabolic pathway

Tags: python, statistics, pathway, api, kegg

What is the quickest way to calculate the number of chemical reactions present in each pathway for a given organism and which online database such as [Kegg](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway.html&ved=2ahUKEwiI9L6GguXqAhXoQhUIHduBCAQQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2QyaydXTKesFiTDlhfFLeU), [MetaCyc](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://metacyc.org/&ved=2ahUKEwj3ut-YguXqAhW4URUIHeufDZwQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1LIpPmxAfCLf4Ppt2OgKiw),[Reactome](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://reactome.org/&ved=2ahUKEwj348CtguXqAhVCXRUIHX24DhMQFjAAegQIChAD&usg=AOvVaw28zRp8yw0zw_85-RfQX1so) is more helpful/reliable for this type of statistics?

Comment: Hello, I think "present" is too ambitious here. I guess "known" is the best you can hope for. But I have not looked at the network data for a while, so I am not sure where is the knowledge now.

Comment: Agreed. However I need to run a global statistics on the number of "known" reactions per pathway...clearly I expect some bias.